# Удаление android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10

Слетела винда, в папке которая создает студия 2.2 AndroidStudioProjects есть важный проект. Если выбирать восстановить Винду без удаления личных файлов и он удалит android studio, то эта папка с проектами тоже удалиться?

Comment: Врядли, но лучше скопируйте этот проект в надежное место. Раз он важный так он давно должен быть в облаках.

Comment: @pavel, ну вот как то тупанул

Comment: заливайте проекты в git и будете спать спокойно:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от того, где находится эта папка. Если в `C:/Users/%USERNAME%/Documents`, то нет.

Также можно:

1. Воспользоваться LiveCD для восстановления Windows;
2. Использовать загрузочную флешку с linux дистрибутивом (например, Ubuntu) для того, чтобы без переустановки операционной системы получить доступ к жесткому диску с файлами;
3. Подключить жесткий диск к другому компьютеру.